# DataBinding GridView C# windows store app

Tags: c#, windows-store-apps

I have a DataTemplate as defined below

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="IconTextDataTemplate">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="220" Height="60">
            <Border Background="#66727272" Width="40" Height="40" Margin="10">
                <Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfPhotos}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>
```

I then have a GridView that uses the DataTemplate

```
<GridView x:Name="gv" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
                  Width="Auto" Height="Auto" SelectionMode="Multiple" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource IconTextDataTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <GridView.ItemsPanel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <WrapGrid MaximumRowsOrColumns="8" 
                  VerticalChildrenAlignment="Top" HorizontalChildrenAlignment="Center" />
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GridView.ItemsPanel>
        </GridView>
```

I then set the GridViews dataContext to a collection

```
gv.DataContext = setCollection;
```

The object setCollection is a collection of objects that has properties of NumberOfPhotos and Title so the binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
                <TextBlock  Text="{Binding Path=NumberOfPhotos}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis"/>
```

works.  However, the object does not have a property for the ImageSource

```
<Image Source="/SampleImage.png" Height="32" Width="32" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
```

Instead of binding to a property of the objects, I want to bind to a compound structure made up of two strings and a property of the object, like so:

```
ImageSource = "/files/thumbnails/" + {Binding Path=Title} + fileType;
```

So when evaluated, the ImageSource becomes

```
/files/thumbnails/titleOfObject.png
```

where the titleOfObject is equal to that value here

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Title}" Margin="10,0,0,0" Width="170" Height="20" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" />
```

How can I make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably better off viewing your bound objects as ViewModels. Conceptually, that means the job of the ViewModel object is to prepare the data for view. That includes things like massaging the title to be bound to a Source attribute. So on your object (or a derived object, or a formal ViewModel of your object), create a property that does that calculation for you.

```
public string TitleImageSource
{
    get
    {
        return string.Format(@"/files/thumbnails/{0}{1}", this.Title, fileType);
    }
}
```

And then bind to that property in your Image.

**An alternative** is to create a converter for the binding. The converter might be something like:

```
public sealed class ImageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.Format(@"/files/thumbnails/{0}{1}", value, parameter);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        return string.Empty;
    }
}
```

Then reference that converter on the Source binding on the Image tag.

Comment: An alternative that I personally don't like very much (but can admit that it's a personal prejudice) is to create a converter that does more or less the same thing and apply that on the binding.

Comment: so the answer is to create a new object of the bound object with the property that calculates the format for you?  I thought of that but it is rather tough since the base class is sealed, I would have to rewrite the bound class.  The other method you mention I am not familiar with, I will look up ViewModels.

Comment: If you cannot alter the object yourself, then yes.